# How to create img tags dynamically from the code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following img tag:

```
  <img  id="cross" runat="server"  />
```

I would like to create several img tags according to data the I'm getting back from the Database. but I'm keep getting an error 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage' does not allow child controls.

How can I create img tag dynamically?

For example if I'm getting back from the database 5 dots(XCoord,YCoord) to be created I want to create new 5 images.

Here is my code:

```
 Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetIncidentsByZone(135, "02/11/2015", "05/12/2015", m_User.CompanyCode)
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then
                For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows()
                    cross.Controls.Add(New HtmlImage() With {.Src = "C:/Inetpub/temp/pointer.gif", .Alt = ""})
                    cross.Style.Add("left", dr("XCoord").ToString() + "px")
                    cross.Style.Add("top", dr("YCoord").ToString() + "px")
                    cross.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:visible")
                Next
            End If
```

Comment: You are trying to add an image tag inside of another image tag.  The error tells you that isn't allowed.  You could add the images to another control that accepts child controls (like a div).

Comment: I'm trying to create a new instance of image tag for each record that coming from the Database. What are you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, your loop needs to look more like this:

```
If Not ds Is Nothing Then
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows()
        Dim newImage as  New HtmlImage() With {.Src = "C:/Inetpub/temp/pointer.gif", .Alt = ""}
        newImage.Style.Add("left", dr("XCoord").ToString() + "px")
        newImage.Style.Add("top", dr("YCoord").ToString() + "px")
        someOtherContainerItemLikeADiv.Controls.Add(newImage)
    Next
End If
```

On each iteration of the loop you need to make a new image, set it's properties and then add that to some kind of control that allows child controls, like a div.